# How to Mock environment in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit, mockery

I'm trying to implement a unit test in Laravel 5.7 I want to mock APP_ENV testing to production or any else as I want.

Unit test code:

```
App::shouldReceive('environment')->with('APP_ENV')->once()->andReturn('production');
```

Code:

```
if (in_array(env('APP_ENV'), ["production", 'local'])) {
    return "This production environment";
}
```

There was 1 error:

```
Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException: Received Mockery_5_Illuminate_Foundation_Application::offsetGet(), but no expectations were specified
```

Comment: In laravel 5.7 you can do `putenv('APP_ENV=production')` though this won't work in all Laravel versions

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
app()['env'] = 'production';
```

Comment: Surprisingly it works :)